# Typescript type assertions - interface with optional members

Tags: typescript

Why interface with optional property is treated differently from interface without? Are all the properties considered optional for type assertion if none of them defined optional explicitly?

```
interface WithOptionalProperty {
    requiredProperty: string;
    optionalProperty?: string;
}

//compilation error 'requiredProperty' is missing
let a = { optionalProperty: '' } as WithOptionalProperty; 

interface WithoutOptionalProperties {
    requiredProperty: string;
    anotherRequiredProperty: string;
}

//but this works as expected
let b = { anotherRequiredProperty: '' } as WithoutOptionalProperties;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because type assertions between types A and B succeed if A is assignable to B or B is assignable to A (simplified explanation).

Neither of these conditions are true in your case 1. But one of these is true in case B (hence the assertion compiles fine).

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Double Assertion : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html#double-assertion

Comment: I'm still get confused what's the point of two-directional check (A->B | B->A)

Comment: `what's the point of two-directional check` Partial safety e.g. You are allowed to easily assert from a parent class to a child class (cause it very well might be polymorphically pointing to a child instance). However you aren't allowed to a highly unsafe assertion without doing a double assertion.